# aws configure list show me nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Assume I am on a Mac and I have a `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[profile cicd]
region = us-west-2
output = json

[profile prod]
region = us-west-2
output = json
```

And also a `~/.aws/credentials` file:

```
[cicd]
aws_access_key_id = 12345 
aws_secret_access_key = 12345

[prod]
aws_access_key_id = 12345 
aws_secret_access_key = 12345
```

If I run:

```
aws configure list
```

I get:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

What have I done wrong?

Also, the company I work for has multiple AWS accounts. The `cicd` profile runs in one AWS account, and the `prod` runs in a different AWS account. A I supposed to record that fact in the AWS config files?

Comment: Append `help` to any awscli command to get some help. For example: `aws configure list help` or `aws configure help` or `aws help`.

Comment: Also be aware that `aws configure list-profiles` will list all local configuration profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws configure list` just lists the **current** AWS credentials that you are using. It doesn't list all the available credentials you have configured on your system. The name of the command is really misleading.

It is currently showing that you have no credentials configured, because you haven't done anything to specify that you want to use one of those profiles in your config/credential files.

If you did something to select a profile, like:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=cicd
```

Then you would see some details about that particular profile when you run `aws configure list`.

Comment: Or equivalently `AWS_PROFILE=cicd aws configure list` or `aws configure list --profile cicd` which doesn't permanently pollute your environment.